# How to control URIs using MVC4 with WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've watched a lot of video tutorials and read even more articles. I don't think I've seen one that answers this question and I'm stuck. :S

I created an MVC4 Application with Web API. Going off of the tutorials I've read I went with a standard naming convention. Say for example, /api/user and /api/user/id, etc.

Now I would like to create CRUD pages for the User entity. Of course, these pages would fit well under the /Admin/ folder, but I can't create a controller that generates views of /Admin/User/Create, /Admin/User/View, etc., since this would require creating a controller called UserController - but this is already created for the WebAPI.

Doesn't it seem standard or at least 'ok' to create CRUD pages for my Entities with this folder structure:

```
Views/Admin/User/
Views/Admin/Product/
etc, etc.
```

This allows each entity/table to have its own folder with its own Create.cshtml, Index.cshtml, etc.

But again, I have already created a WebAPI with this structure:

```
api/User/
api/Product/
```

So, now I want to create some Admin pages to manage the database. When I create a MVC controller with read/write using Entity Framework I can't figure out what to name the controller to give me the URI structure I'm wanting.

Of course, I don't really care what the controllers are called, but I don't know what steps are required to get the URI structure. For example, I created an MVC controller and named it AdminProduct, but now I have to go to /AdminProduct/ to see those pages.

Can someone point me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have two controllers with the same name as long as they are in different namespaces. For example, I add all of my `System.Web.Http.ApiController` classes under the /Controllers/Api folder in my project. By default, Visual Studio will include these controllers in a namespace called `<ProjectName>.Controllers.Api`. Then, inside the /Controllers folder you can add `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` classes there, and they will be in the `<ProjectName>.Controllers` namespace. So, long-story-short, you can have an MVC controller named UserController and a WebApi controller named UserController, and there is no conflict.

The views for your MVC controller actions, like `/User/Create` and `/User/Delete` should be put under the `/Views/User/` folder of your project - each with the same name as the action in the UserController. As far as having admin pages, why not create an `AdminController` or using the `[Authorize]` action filter on those actions you want secured?

I'm not sure I understood your entire problem. ASP.NET MVC binds controller names and actions to views by this convention.

Comment: You answered it very well. Placing the WebAPI controllers in a folder called API is a really good solution and I think that takes care of the conflict I was having. Thank you!

Comment: Your solution worked great to resolve the conflict, but when I create a read/write controller using EntityFramework the User folder is created in /Views/ automatically. I tried copying it to the /Views/Admin/User/ folder, but it won't load this way. Probably a separate question. :P

Comment: ...and perhaps I marked the question as answered too promptly. You mentioned creating an AdminController. I thought about that, but I just don't get how the folder structure relates to the public URI. I "think" I am happy with a subfolder for each entity/table. That way each can have it's own CRUD .cshtml files. Is there a way of doing this within a single controller - AdminController? Or would a single controller mean a single folder with all of the CRUD cshtml files for every entity in that one folder?

Comment: I sounds to me like you are really confused on the difference between an API controller and an MVC controller. Do you think you need to have views for all of your CRUD actions? The answer is no, you don't. It makes sense to have views if you need to display data to the user. But why would you need a view for a PUT, POST, or DELETE action?